# Help me identify the blown part, SMD, 5-pin "5AH10"

Tags: usb, integrated-circuit, identification, repair, usb-hub

Pic 1 (the ic):

[image: Ic]

Pic 2 (the ic):

[image: Ic]

Pic 3 (the ic):

[image: Ic]

Pic 4 (the hub board):

[image: full board]

Pic 5 (back side of the hub ic right above the big ribbon cable female connector):

[image: back side of the hub]

This IC is found in the USB hub of the HP Pavilion 15 laptop. The IC has 5 pins and is responsible for the 2 USB ports not functioning.

The reason might be the high current consumption of the 2 USBs at the same time, the hub is called "DAG75ATBAD0 REV D", the laptop's model is 15-Cb004nx, also, the blown IC has what I assume to be "5AH10" written on it, but I searched online and I can't identify it.

It is placed very close to the data ribbon cable connection and I assume they are connected, it also has 3 close capacitors; 2 are very small and one is bigger with a close by empty footprint, moreover there aren't any ICs elsewhere on the board besides 2 ICs called 3342p which are transient safety ICs description: "4-Line, Uni-directional, Ultra-low Capacitance, Transient Voltage Suppressor".

I just want to know what it does so I might be able to replace it with another IC with similar use.

Comment: Just by looking at the marking of the chip, it looks very similar to the way Silergy marks their chips. But I doubt they have 7 year old (based on laptop model) documentation for specifically this product. If I had to guess, it's a SOT23-5 LDO...

Comment: The DAG75 is not a USB hub, it is some audio interface, The part itself is most likely a Hi-Side power switch. The entire board can be found even on Amazon, https://www.amazon.com/yungluner-15-CB077TX-15-CB035WM-DAG75ATBADO-Interface/dp/B0CL5MGS9G

Comment: @AhmedH20, I've added the part number and description into your question title. This means that readers don't have to open your question to see what the chip is. It also helps search engine results.

Comment: in cases like this, I always want to know *why* there has been so much burning. Typically these things should have protection against shorts on USB +5V etc, so when you get this degree of burning some serious internal malfunction may have happened. Risk is that you change out the failed device but the real cause is not fixed and the same happens again, possibly with worse results. If you can replace the whole board at reasonable cost, that looks like an easier and better option to me.

Comment: I bought a very bad and fake usb hub and when I disassembled the hub I found it is a direct connection not a single component just wires connecting the usb together, also i had a short circuit with the arduino 10 times before it failed. The arduino is ok though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [GMT G517H1T11U](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2202132000_GMT-Global-Mixed-mode-Tech-G517AH1TP1U_C2840474.pdf) power distribution switch.

[image]

I couldn't find a picture of this exact device, but of the G517C1T11U that shows the marking style matches:

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Power-Distribution-Switches_GMT-Global-Mixed-mode-Tech-G517C1T11U_C5162523.html))

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate your help, I think it is indeed the ic now I can work from here.